# Insert data into kusto table using flow

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Can we insert data into kusto table using flow?

I tried to insert data into kusto table using .ingest inline command but it throws a bad request error shown below:

Bad request: Control commands (starting with a dot '.') cannot be served from the query endpoint unless they are .show control commands.\r\nPlease provide the following information when contacting the Kusto.

So can we insert data into kusto table using flow?

Answer (score 2):

it is possible, you just need to choose the `Run control command...` action instead of the `Run query ...` option (as `.ingest`, like any other command that starts with a dot (`.`) is a control command, and not a query)

that said, using direct ingestion is not necessarily recommended for large scale - you can read more about why here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/

> Inline ingestion (push): A control command (.ingest inline) is sent to the engine, with the data to be ingested being a part of the command text itself. This method is primarily intended for ad-hoc testing purposes, and should not be used for production purposes.

Comment: Ran with run control command and visualize result,Chart Type was mandatory field. Specified Chart Type as 'Pie Chart' or 'Bar Chat' I got the following error:
  ClassName: System.ArgumentException,
  Message: Parameter is not valid,
  StackTraceString: HtmlVisualization.ChartRenderer.MergeImages at HtmlVisualization.ChartRenderer.RenderPieChart(DataTable dataTable)  at Kusto.Flow.FlowVisualizer.CreateVisualization(DataTable dt, String clusterConnectionString, String dbName, String query, String chartType) at Kusto.Flow.KustoRequestManager.__DisplayClass14_0.<RunKustoAndVisualizeResults

Answer (score 0):

@Yoni L
Thank you it worked but we need to choose Chart Type as Html Table